# Open multiple images in gallery intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I need to open multiple images in gallery to view by sliding...
I know how to open 1 image..

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + "/sdcard/test.jpg"), "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

How can i view multiple images to view them all by sliding in a single intent.?
I have the path of the images... And i need to view them in gallery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cant do that.... You need to create a new view activity

Answer (score 3):

The EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE option is set on the intent through the Intent.putExtra() method to select multiple images

Multiple Image selection available only for above **API 18**

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
```

Full intent code is here:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(); intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"),1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can straight away show multiple images by accessing into your device's default gallery app.

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to implement multi-selection of images in gallery:

1.Intent for getting multiple images

2.Define custom gallery with fetching and loading photos from native gallery.

Intent for getting multiple images:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
```

For implementation of gallery see this link: http://www.technotalkative.com/android-select-multiple-photos-from-gallery/

it fetches multiple images and shows them in a `gridview`